# Efficient way to check password is in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system that generates a batch of random codes up to 100 at a time. They are then inserted in to a database. I am using a code generator and it would be pretty unlikely a similar code could be created again but to make sure I want to check the DB for a duplicate anyway. My theory..

```
  $amount_of_codes


  while ($x != $amount_of_codes)
    {
    $code = gencode();
    $mysql_check = "SELECT code FROM data WHERE code = '$code'";
    $mysql_check_result = mysql_query($mysql_check);
    $check = mysql_num_rows($mysql_check_result);
     if (!$check)
      {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO data(code) values('$code')")
      $x++
      } 
    }
```

seems messy, any better ideas?

Comment: imo thats the right way to do it, for more speed: create an index for the code column

Comment: This is a good way to do it. But you don't need to have unique passwords. You need unique users, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `Code` Column a UNIQUE constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Code
(
  Code ..
..
  CONSTRAINT Code_Unique UNIQUE (Code),
..
);
```

When inserting you only need to capture database exceptions/errors, not worrying if a Code already exists.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* messy. More importantly, it's also subject to race conditions where another process could insert that code in between your check and your insert.

If you want to avoid that, make the code column a unique key then just try to insert it. If it's already there, that atomic operation will return an error or raise an exception, which you can check/catch.

By doing the after-the-attempt check, you lose nothing since you have to check anyway (in case the afore-mention race condition bites you). But what you gain is atomicity and cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Really simple solution,  make sure your function witch puts in the codes does not put in a code witch already exits.

Basically:

generate code

chek if the code exists

yes -> generate new code

no -> put code in db

No time for script sorry